# Assing a variable and use it inside of if statement shell scripting

Tags: shell

I am new to shell scripting and trying to make a few small scripts. I got stuck when i tried to write if condition. In the code below i am trying to get the $5 value from df and trying to use it in if condition. However the code doesn't work.

```
 #!/bin/sh

temp = $(df -h | awk '$NF=="/"{$5}')
if [ $temp > 60 ] ; then
 df -h | awk '$NF=="/" {printf("%s\n"),$5}'
 (date -d "today" +"Date:%Y.%m.%d"" Hour: %H:%M")
fi

#end
```

So i've figured out something and changed my code into this:

```
temp=$(df -h | awk '$NF=="/"{$5}')
if [ "$((temp))" -gt 0 ] ; then
 df -h | awk '$NF=="/" {printf("%s\n"),$5}'
 (date -d "today" +"Date:%Y.%m.%d"" Hour: %H:%M")
fi

#end
```

And now , i'm trying to get the integer value of the $5 variable. It returns a percentage and i want to compare this percentage with %60. How can i do that ?

Comment: Do you simply want to retrieve fifth column from `df -h` output?

Comment: Yes and also i want if statement to work for both of the df -h  and (date ... ) part.

Comment: https://www.shellcheck.net tells you about most problems in your snippet.

Comment: Thank you that helped a lot.

Comment: In your first line of the updated code, you're not telling awk to actually `print` the 5th field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's see what shellcheck.net has to tell us:

```
Line 1:
  #!/bin/sh
^-- SC1114: Remove leading spaces before the shebang.

Line 3:
temp = $(df -h | awk '$NF=="/"{$5}')
     ^-- SC1068: Don't put spaces around the = in assignments.

Line 4:
if [ $temp > 0 ] ; then
     ^-- SC2086: Double quote to prevent globbing and word splitting.
           ^-- SC2071: > is for string comparisons. Use -gt instead.
           ^-- SC2039: In POSIX sh, lexicographical > is undefined.
```

Um, ok, after a little fixing:

```
#!/bin/sh
temp=$(df -h | awk '$NF=="/"{$5}')
if [ "$temp" -gt 0 ] ; then  
   df -h | awk '$NF=="/" {printf("%s\n"),$5}'
   (date -d "today" +"Date:%Y.%m.%d"" Hour: %H:%M")
fi
```

The `[ ... ]` command is the same as `test` command. Test does not have `<` comparison for numbers. It has `-gt` (greater then). See [man test](https://linux.die.net/man/1/test).
This will run now, but definitely not do what you want. You want the fifth column of df output, ie. the use percents. Why do you need -h/human readable output? We dont need that. Which row of df output do you want? I guess you don't want the header, ie. the first row: `Filesystem           1K-blocks      Used Available Use% Mounted on`. Let's filter the columns with the disc name, I choose /dev/sda2. We can filter the row that has the first word equal to /dev/sda2 with `grep "^/dev/sda2 "`. The we need to get the value on the fifth column with `awk '{print $5}'`. We need to get rid of the '%' sign too, otherwise shell will not interpret the value as a number, with `sed 's/%//'` or better with `tr -d '%'`. Specifying `date -d"today"` is the same as just `date`. Enclosing a command in `(...)` runs it in subshell, we don't need that.

```
#!/bin/sh
temp=$(df | grep "^/dev/sda2 " | awk '{print $5}' | tr -d '%')
if [ "$temp" -gt 0 ]; then  
   echo "${temp}%"
   date +"Date:%Y.%m.%d Hour: %H:%M"
fi
```

This is a simple, that if use percentage on disc /dev/sda2 is higher then 0, then it will print the use percentage and print current date and time in a custom format.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using GNU tools, you can narrow the `df` output to just what you need:

```
pct=$( df --output=pcent / | grep -o '[[:digit:]]\+' )
if [[ $pct -gt 60 ]]; then ...
```